# MyDatePickerModule is not an NgModule

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

estoy usando este modulo en angular 2 y se esta presentando este error, me pueden ayudar.

`app.module.ts`

```
import {MyDatePickerModule} from "mydatepicker";
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
TestComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
MyDatePickerModule,
MaterialModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`test.component.ts`

```
private myDatePickerOptions: IMyOptions = {
 dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
 firstDayOfWeek: 'mo',
 sunHighlight: true,
 inline: false,
 width: '60%'
};
```

`test.component.html`

```
<my-date-picker [locale]="locale" class="card-size"    [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
                (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)">

</my-date-picker>
```

Comment: ¿Solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Perdón, estoy usando ngPrime

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza mejor:

```
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/datepicker';
```

y para usarlo en el template (HTML) es:

```
<label for="example-start-date" class="form-control-label">Fecha Inicio:</label>
<div class="card-block">
  <div id="example-start-date" style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="example.start_date" name="start_date" required></datepicker>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes revisar la siguiente página: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es un [bug en la versión 1.3.0](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker/issues/172) de mydatepicker. Tienes varias opciones:

1. Esperar a que arreglen el bug y saquen una actualización, entonces actualizar mydatepicker.
2. Utilizar una versión anterior que parece que a algunos usuarios le funciona:
   `npm install mydatepicker@1.0.37`
3. Utilizar una versión anterior de angular-cli, que parece que compila correctamente:
   `npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.21`